# Byte[] sent across SocketChannel but not received

Tags: java, networking, socketchannel

I've been having some trouble with a project that requires a bit of networking, where data is sent over a `SocketChannel` but is never received. I was able to replicate the issue with a simple localhost chatroom program (sorry if it's a bit messy):

```
public class Main {

    private Sender sender; 

    private Receiver receiver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main foo = new Main();
        //The ports are switched in the other running version of this
        foo.receiver = new Receiver("192.168.1.108", 12348);
        foo.sender = new Sender("192.168.1.108", 12347);
        foo.takeUserInput();
    }
    private void takeUserInput() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter something");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input = null;
            try {
                input = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sender.send(input);
        }
    }
}


public class Receiver implements Closeable {

    private InetSocketAddress bindAddress;

    private ServerSocketChannel server;

    private ListenThread listenThread;

    public Receiver(String address, int port) {
        bindAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
        bind();
        listen();
    }

    public void bind() {
        try {
            server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            server.configureBlocking(true);
            server.bind(bindAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Bound to port " + bindAddress.getPort());
    }
    public void listen() {
        listenThread = new ListenThread();
        listenThread.start();
    }
    private class ListenThread extends Thread {

        private SocketChannel client;

        public void run() {
            try {
                client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("Received connection from " + client.getLocalAddress());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while((server.isOpen()) && (client.isOpen())) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Reading");
                    client.read(buffer);
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer.array()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        server.close();
        listenThread.client.close();
    }
}

public class Sender implements Closeable {

    private InetSocketAddress connectAddress;

    private SocketChannel clientChannel;

    public Sender(String address, int port) {
        connectAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);
        connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        while((clientChannel == null) || (!(clientChannel.isConnected()))) {
            try {
                clientChannel = SocketChannel.open(connectAddress);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Connected to " + clientChannel.getLocalAddress());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send(String message) {
        byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        try {
            clientChannel.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Sent message");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        clientChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Here's the logs from one version:

```
Bound to port 12348
Reading
Connected to /192.168.1.108:64699
Enter something
thing
Sent message
Enter something
```

And the other:

```
Bound to port 12347
Reading
Connected to /192.168.1.108:64698
Enter something
```

So, I know that both programs successfully establish connections to the other, and start reading, but when I send something over a SocketChannel from one end, the other just remains stuck on the `read()`call in `ListenThread`.

How can I make the client successfully read what is sent?

Comment: No they do not connect to each other. The ports are different.

Comment: Oh, where are the 64698/9 ports coming from? I was thinking that those were just random ports that connections get redirected to before reaching the destination (something to do with  blocking?), but I don't really know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two issues.

1. As mentioned by @Ethan F, the ports are different.  You should use the same port number.
2. Your `listen()` method in the Receiver class never get called.  You need to call this method to accept connection.

   ```
   foo.receiver = new Receiver("192.168.1.108", 12348);
   foo.receiver.listen();
   ```

Comment: Well, that was dumb of me. I put the listen() call back in, and it worked fine, so I guess the big issue was in the code of my main project. Thanks